# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0×0)　エラー

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

学校のプロジェクトで作っているTo Do Listアプリについて、困っています。

私が使っているのは
Xcode Version 8.1
Swift 2.0　　です。

私はまだプログラミングを始めたばかりの初心者で、このアプリもチュートリアルを見て作っています。

こちらが私の見ているチュートリアルです:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Md0KDy6DCAc

また、この方のフルコードが載っているサイトがこれです：
https://github.com/mobilespace/ToDoList

コードを全て書き終えてシミュレーターを起動し、To Do Itemを足そうとしたのですが、Itemをセーブしようと Save を押したらコードへ戻り、

"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0×0)"

と出てきました。

出てきたところは AddToDoItemController.swiftの

```
 delegate?.addToDoItemToList(toDoItemField.text!)
```

というラインです。

デバッグコンソールには

> To Do List[55266:2935900] [MC] Reading from private effective user
>   settings. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value (lldb)

と出ていました。

bad instructionということは、きちんと指示ができていない、ということだというのは分かるのですが、何が足りないのでしょうか？
また、何が足りないのかを調べる方法はありますか？

コードのコピーです：

AddToDoItemController.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol AddToDoItemControllerDelegate: class {
    func addToDoItemToList(_ text:String)
}

class AddToDoItemController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var toDoItemField: UITextField!

    weak var delegate: AddToDoItemControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func cancelBarButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveBarButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.addToDoItemToList(toDoItemField.text!)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, AddToDoItemControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var toDoList: NSMutableArray = ["Go get groceries", "Walk the dog", "Watch a movie", "Do your homework"]

    var completedToDoList: [Int:String] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        resetAccessoryType()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return toDoList.count 
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = toDoList[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func resetAccessoryType() {
        for row in 0..<toDoList.count {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .none {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                completedToDoList[completedToDoList.count] = toDoList[indexPath.row] as? String
                toDoList.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)
            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }
    }

    func addToDoItemToList(_ text:String) {
        toDoList[toDoList.count] = text

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "AddToDoItemSegue") {
            let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let addToDoItemViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! AddToDoItemController

            addToDoItemViewController.delegate = self
        } else if(segue.identifier == "CompletedToDoItemsSegue") {
            let completedToDoItemsController = segue.destination as! CompletedToDoItemsController
            completedToDoItemsController.completedToDoList = completedToDoList 
        }
    }

}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: デバッグコンソール(エディター画面の下側右)にはもう少し何かメッセージが表示されていないでしょうか?

Comment: "To Do List[55266:2935900] [MC] Reading from private effective user
settings. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
Optional value (lldb) " と出ていました！

Comment: 今のXcode/simulatorは余計なメッセージを多数混入させるのでちょっと見にくいのですが、一番肝心なのは **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** の部分です。実行時エラー(いわゆるアプリがcrashした状態になっています)発生時には **EXC_...** の部分はほとんど役に立たないことが多いので、そう言った「メッセージ」になっている部分を探すようにしてください。ここ日本語版スタック・オーバーフローでもそのキーワーで検索すれば多数の記事が見つかるのですが、少し多すぎるのと、古いXcode用の記事が上位に来たりするようですね…。

Comment: クラス`ViewController`のプロパティ`var toDoList: NSMutableArray = ["Go get groceries", "Walk the dog", "Watch a movie", "Do your homework"]`の項目数を増やし、テーブルビューに収まらない数、つまりスクロールしないと全体を見渡せない数にしてください。そして、プログラムをシミュレータで起動し、行をタップして、チェックマークをいくつか入れ、スクロールしてみてください。プログラムがクラッシュするはずです。リンク先のサンプルコードに対して、上の処理を行って、クラッシュするのを確認しています。なにが言いたいかというと、このサンプルコードには、致命的な欠陥があります。学習の対象として（もちろん実用性も）不適です。ほかのToDoアプリのチュートリアルを探して、そちらを学習したほうがいいでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実は古いXcode(と言うかSwiftのシステム側の実行時処理)では、 **`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`** が発生しても、原因となる行を示してくれなかったのですが、現在は改善されているので、調べなければいけないのは、エラー表示のあった行:

```
delegate?.addToDoItemToList(toDoItemField.text!)
```

だけに絞り込んでいいでしょう。

上記のエラーが出るケース(双方とも内部的には同じことですが)は大きく2つあります。

- 強制アンラップ(後置の`!`)を使用している箇所でアンラップされる値が`nil`である
- `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`型の値が`nil`なのに、それを`nil`が許されない場所で使っている

該当の行にはもろに後置の`!`が使われていますし`toDoItemField`は`UITextField!`型、つまり`ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UITextField>`型ですから、どちらにも該当していると言うことになります。

ちなみにOptionalだとか`nil`だとか「アンラップ」「強制アンラップ」とかの概念はSwift言語学習の肝と言ってもいい部分の一つなので、まだ十分理解できていない場合には、解説記事などを探し出してしっかり学習しておいてください。

---

まずはコードでもろに見えている`toDoItemField.text!`の部分です。

(ちなみに`!`は「私のアプリをクラッシュさせて演算子」(Crash me operator)と通称されています。可能なかぎり使わないようにしないと予期せぬところでアプリがクラッシュします。)

この式は、もし`toDoItemField.text`の値が`nil`だと上記のメッセージを出してアプリがクラッシュしてしまうのですが、「初期値は`nil`ではなく、空文字列(`""`)」「Saveをタップする前に何か文字を入力していれば`nil`にはならない」と言う2点から今回はおそらく原因ではないでしょう。

ただ、もう少し確実に安全なコードにしたいなら、

```
delegate?.addToDoItemToList(toDoItemField.text ?? "")
```

と書く手もあります。`??`はOptional-bindingとかに比べると紹介している記事が少ないように思いますが、`??`の左辺が`nil`の場合には右辺の値で置き換えてくれる、と言う演算子です。

---

さて、残るは`UITextField!`型である`toDoItemField`の値が`nil`である、と言う可能性です。`@IBOutlet`にするプロパティは通常`ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`型にするのですが、それが`nil`のままで実際のUI部品につながらない場合がいくつか考えられます。

1. StoryboardでのConnectionの張り間違い
2. ViewControllerをstoryboardからインスタンス化せずコンストラクタを直接呼び出した場合

あなたの場合、2.のようなコードは書いておらず、みなstoryboardで設定しているようですから調べるべきは1.の方ということになります。

---

と言うわけで、またstoryboardの設定を確認してみたほうがよさそうです。

Storyboardエディターで`AddToDoItemController`内の`UITextField`を選択し、Inspector等で接続を確認してみてください。

[image: Outlet接続確認]

残念ながら今のXcodeでは、storyboardで接続した後でソースコードの方を編集すると、見かけ上は接続されているように見えるのに実際はうまくいかないということがあるようなので、一度 **×** を押して削除した後でもう一度接続しなおしたほうが確実かもしれません。

---

いかがでしょうか。これでは上手く動くようにできないという場合には、例によってコメント等でお知らせください。

ちなみにあなたのご質問中で「Swift 2.0　　です。」と記載されていますが、「リンク先のGitHub内のコードはSwift2で書かれている」のですが、あなたが質問本文中に記載されたコードはSwift3用になっています。

Comment: [ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/implicitlyunwrappedoptional)は、このリファレンスによると、Deprecatedになっています。Xcode 8のエディタに打ち込んでも、警告が出ないので、見落としがちですが。

Comment: @nagonsoftware さん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。[SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md)により`T!`で表されるデータ型は`@_autounwrapped`属性(抽象的な説明用の属性で陽に使用することはできない)が付いた`Optional<T>`型なのだ、とされており、実際の挙動もそのように修正されています。ただ普通に`T!`型の変数を`var a: T!`のように宣言して`type(of:a)`を表示させると`ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>`のように表示されますし、`@_autounwrapped`属性は非公開でコンパイラー内部でのみ使用されるものなので、説明用には`ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>`を使わざるをえないかと思っています。ただ、`ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`が独立したデータ型として使えるかのような表現は避けた方がよいでしょうね。この回答ではその心配はないと思っていますが、今後は気をつけたいと思います。